# Multi-element output from step in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a step in the job which will output multiple file names which then could be iterated in another step. Here is my test workflow:

```yaml
name: test-workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Test1
        id: test1
        run: |
          for f in $(ls $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/.github/workflows); do
            echo "file: $f"
            echo "::set-output name=f::$f"
          done

      - name: Test2
        run: |
          for file in "${{ steps.test1.outputs.f }}"; do
            echo "$file detected"
          done
```

However, given `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/.github/workflows` really contains multiple files (all committed to repo), step `Test2` prints out only last file name listed in the step `Test1` by `ls`.
How can I set output `f` from the step `Test1` to multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you ovrwrite output. Please try to pass an array as output:

```yaml
name: test-workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Test1
        id: test1
        run: |
          h=""
          for g in $(ls $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/.github/workflows); do
            echo "file: $g"
            h="${h} $g"
          done

          echo "::set-output name=h::$h"

      - name: Test2
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.test1.outputs.h }}; do
            echo "$file.. detected"
          done
```